# how well would a robust mixed model fit these data? R (rlmer)

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, nonparametric, robust

I want to investigate `Y ~ X1 * X2 + (1|ID` on [this dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73831029/error-bars-look-weird-in-ggplot2-continuos-y-x-categorical-x-r?noredirect=1#comment130370220_73831029) (there's a plot of these data in that post too, it's the same [dataframe](https://github.com/Larissa-Cury/datapost2309.git))

- Y is a continuos outcome variable. X1 and X2 are both two 2-level categorical predictors. X1 ("CATEGORIES") accounts for "Year of testing" and X2 "test1 or test2" (MY_GROUP). All data come from the same group of participants (n = 21), each participant has four scores (n = 84). I wanna see the possible effects of X1 and X2 on Y as well as if they're interacting
- Problems:

```
mod1 <- lmer(CONT_Y ~ CATEGORIES * MY_GROUP + (1|PARTICIPANTS), data = myData3)
```

[image: plots]

- My question is: would a robust lmer regression account for these problems? I mean, probably it wouldn't be "THE best" solution, but **how well would a robust lmer fit these data?**

```
library("robustlmm")
mod2 <- rlmer(CONT_Y ~ CATEGORIES * MY_GROUP + (1|PARTICIPANTS), data = myData3)
```

- note: I didn't want to exclude any participants since I only have 21...
- note2: I've never performed a robust regression/bootstrapping/sandwich before, any tips would be much appreaciated :)
- note 3: I'm kinda *running out of time* to hand in this analysis, so I'm aware that maybe, a robust fit isn't "THE" best, as I've said, but would it be enough for a preliminary analysis? Mainly: **what problems would it correct for, which would remain?**
- A repeated measures Anova would be just fine in my case, bu my date doesn't seem to be normally distributed and I didnt find a non parameteic alternative..
- Any thoughts would be much appreciated!!