# How do we report significant tests without p-values? Reliance on confidence intervals

Tags: r, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, p-value, bootstrap

I'm pretty much reporting [these results](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590853/bootstrapping-a-linear-mixed-model-with-rs-lmeresampler-or-lme4-or-a-robust-reg). I've bootstrapped my sample using [lmersampler](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmeresampler/index.html), which does not provide p-values for bootstrapped models. I relied on confidence interval boundaries to justify if the estimates were either *significant* (CI didn't contain zero) or *not* (it crossed zero). **How would be the best way to report that**?

So far, I've included a column called 'significance' and manually included sig or ns, based on the CI, but I'd like to know if there's a better approach to that.

Comment: Report for whom?

Comment: to a journal submission, @Dave

Comment: What does the journal want? Many journals have guides about how to report statistics, either made explicit in the submission instructions or implicit in other publications in that journal.