# How to manually calculate p-values for lmers?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, t-test, p-value

Hopefully this is not a duplicate. Provided the t-statistic, SE and 95% CI, **how can I manually calculate p-values for lmers in R?** More details in the quoted link below.

I've used `lmersampler` to calculate a bootstrapped version of my model. However, there seems to be a bug with the `bootstrap_pvals` function, as it was kindly answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603471/p-values-and-confidence-intervals-are-not-matching?noredirect=1#comment1119377_603471) ]

- I have the **estimates**, **SEs** (from which I can calculate the t-stats) and the **95% CI**:

```
## the model:

mod1 <- lmer(CONT_Y ~ YEAR * MY_GROUP + (1|PARTICIPANTS), data = data)


mod1_boot <- bootstrap(mod1, .f = fixef, type = "case", B = 1000,
                       resample = c(TRUE, FALSE))

## estimates and SEs:

Number of resamples: 1000 

                 term   observed   rep.mean        se         bias
1         (Intercept) 17.6114286 17.6050494 0.4637105 -0.006379144
2            YEARB     1.1438095  1.1572290 0.5018944  0.013419524
3            GROUP2    0.9147619  0.9257567 0.3960487  0.010994762
4        YEARB:GROUP2 -0.6023810 -0.6216186 0.5922274 -0.019237619

## t-stats:

term/se

## CI: 
> confint(mod1_boot, type = "norm")
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  term                estimate  lower  upper type  level
  <chr>                  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1 (Intercept)           17.6   16.7   18.5   norm   0.95 ##should be sig
2 YEAR2021              1.14   0.147  2.11  norm   0.95 ##should be sig
3 GROUP2                0.915  0.128  1.68  norm   0.95 ##should be sig
4 YEARB:GROUP2         -0.602 -1.74   0.578 norm   0.95 ##should be ns
```

- **Question** : provided that, *how do I manually calculate the p-values for the model in R?*
- data:

```
data <- structure(list(PARTICIPANTS = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                        7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                        10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                                        14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 
                                        17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 
                                        20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), CONT_Y = c(19.44, 20.07, 19.21, 
                                                                                  16.35, 11.37, 12.82, 19.42, 18.94, 19.59, 20.01, 19.7, 17.92, 
                                                                                  18.78, 19.21, 19.27, 18.46, 19.52, 20.02, 16.19, 19.97, 13.83, 
                                                                                  15.93, 14.79, 21.55, 18.8, 19.42, 19.27, 19.37, 17.14, 14.45, 
                                                                                  17.63, 20.01, 20.28, 17.93, 19.36, 20.15, 16.06, 17.04, 19.16, 
                                                                                  20.1, 16.44, 18.39, 18.01, 19.05, 18.04, 19.69, 19.61, 16.88, 
                                                                                  19.02, 20.42, 18.27, 18.43, 18.08, 17.1, 19.98, 19.43, 19.71, 
                                                                                  19.93, 20.11, 18.41, 20.31, 20.1, 20.38, 20.29, 13.6, 18.92, 
                                                                                  19.05, 19.13, 17.75, 19.15, 20.19, 18.3, 19.43, 19.8, 19.83, 
                                                                                  19.53, 16.14, 21.14, 17.37, 18.73, 16.51, 17.51, 17.06, 19.42
                                        ), CATEGORIES = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
                                                                    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
                                                                                                                            "B"), class = "factor"), MY_GROUP = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
                                                                                                                                                                            1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L
                                                                                                                            ), .Label = c("G1", "G2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                         -84L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
 


### rename collumn:

data <- data %>%  rename(., YEAR = CATEGORIES)
```